# iOS Scroll Inertia and Scroll Bar with HTML Table

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll

I made a `HTML` Table with a fixed left column (the code is a simplified version of another post on SO). When I view this on the iOS Simulator, the right half of the table scrolls correctly, however, it does not display a scrollbar, and it does not scroll with inertia.

Example of Table: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/94aP4/

Here is the basic code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="leftColumn">Row 1</td>
                <td>efhiubcebucefbuiceguceuceiuceuceu0v8cev8ceserybewqbyuqw0uqr0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #tableContainer {
        width: 200px;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        margin-left:5em;
        overflow-y:visible;
        padding-bottom:1px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border-top: 3px solid grey;
    }
    td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey;
        border-top-width:0px;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .leftColumn {
        position:absolute;
        width:5em;
        left:0;
        top:auto;
        border-right: 0px none black;
        border-top-width:3px;
        /*only relevant for first row*/
        margin-top:-3px;
        /*compensate for top border*/
    }
```

Does anyone know how to activate inertia scrolling, and display the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this the following way:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; //adding this line will enable inertial scrolling
```

Source: http://cooshtee.com/blog/2012/11/add-inertial-scrolling-to-a-fixed-height-div-in-ios/